# How to display AdMob banner ad at the bottom of the screen programmatically?(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I'm new to Kotlin and Android. I want to display an AdMob banner ad at the bottom of the screen programmatically. But I can only display it at the top of the screen. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activityMain"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/rootImageView"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/testTextView"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.Color
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.ToneGenerator
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(useAdMob){ initAdMob(); }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    fun initAdMob()
    {
        MobileAds.initialize(this);

        val adView = AdView(this);
        adView.adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        adView.adUnitId = if(testAdMob) idAdMobBannerForTest else idAdMobBanner1;
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        activityMain.addView(adView);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        
        val lp = adView.layoutParams;
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        println(">>>> adView, width: ${lp.width}, height: ${lp.height}");
    }
}
```

I've searched a lot for the solution, for example, try to:

```
addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)
```

or add in xml:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

But these seems unavailable in the newest version of Android Studio.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a constraint layout in your xml, not a relative layout. So adding a RelativeLayout rule isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise not doing this programatically, but you can use [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet) to set Constraint layout rules programatically. Looks something like this:

```
adView.id = View.generateViewId() // Need to give view an id

ConstraintSet().apply {
    connect(adView.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
    applyTo(constraintLayout) // Your constraint layout here
}
```

This is equivalent to in xml doing

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: How to get the constraintLayout?

Comment: With kotlin just type the id of your layout - activityMain - and kotlin synthetics should get it for you. In older android you'd do findViewById(R.id.activityMain)

Comment: One more question: I want to display a rectangle of red color before the ad is received, that's why I set the background color of adView to red. But the red color doesn't appear until the ad is received. I ever want to create a view with red background, and then set the adView as it's child, so I need to get the height of the adView before it appears. But I get a (-2) value out of the lp.height . How to solve?

Comment: I println (adView.height) it gets out a 0.

Comment: -2 is the layout param constant for WRAP_CONTENT, the problem is you're getting the height before it has been determined. Views have a psuedo 'lifecycle' that goes init -> measure -> layout -> draw. The size of a view isn't determined until measure happens. Getting widths and heights of 0 for your view almost always means you're trying to get the dimensions before measure has happened.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how adView loading behavior works without testing it myself, the problem might be that you're just trying too early, before an ad loads the height might actually be 0, the alpha might be 0, or the visibility might be GONE, or you have a different problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use constraint layout try this below code...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/bannerAd"
   ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

and in kotlin file

```
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    var mAdView = findViewById(R.id.bannerAd)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Comment: The bad thing about this is you're always creating and adding an AdView to the screen even when not wanted.